# How can I make a blogger.com template?

Tags: templates, blogger

How can I make a template for blogger.com?

Comment: http://www.google.co.uk/#hl=en&q=blogger+template+tutorial ...

Comment: @Rushyo - this site is intended to be the place where Google ends up when someone asks this question.  Posting a link that Googles the answer seems counterproductive to that goal.

Comment: I think it's a http://superuser.com thing.

Comment: @tvanfosson maybe but this site is also intended for <em>programming</em> questions that don't have a thousands answers when you search Google for just the questions word... nah?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially, you make an HTML page using the special Blogger tags to get access to your blog's settings and data. Starting from an existing template is probably the easiest way to get going if you just want to make a few tweaks.  If you can't find any similar to what you want you can create it from scratch.  See the template walk-through at http://www.google.com/support/blogger/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=42068.